Prove: Particle filter converges to the correct distribution
I am implementing a particle filter to finish a SLAM like task. I use the particle filter to estimate the position of an object.
Now, I want to prove that the result of the particle filter will converge to the correct value (distribution) after enough iterations.
May I have any hint from you to prove it? How can I start? What should I provide for you to finish this proof problem?

There are a ton of papers about this kind of thing, e.g.
Hu, Xiao-Li, Thomas B. Schon, and Lennart Ljung. "A basic convergence result for particle filtering." IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing 56.4 (2008): 1337-1348.

There are different kinds of convergence, and different results, depending on the different assumptions you can make about your particle filter.
Here is a commonly cited paper (>1000 citations) for these kind of results:
Crisan, Dan; Doucet, Arnaud, A survey of convergence results on particle filtering methods for practitioners, IEEE Trans. Signal Process. 50, No. 3, 736-746 (2002). ZBL1369.60015.
